# Windows: install fonts from cmd/.bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, fonts, installation, cmd

anyone know how to install font files (.ttf, .TTF, .otf, .OTF, etc etc) through the command prompt on windows?

as i understand it, it requires moving the text file to the correct folder and then also creating a registry value i think? but I havent been able to find one that is confirmed working.

a note: I am using windows 8 so that might make a difference.

another note: what I am trying to do is batch install fonts that I ripped from MKV files. (so this will be a function that is part of a larger .bat file, i can post the code if needed)

Comment: There's no way to do it wuthout a third party tools (at least an additional DLL/EXE file). While you can manually add a font via file copy and modifying registry, the system won't still be aware of the new font and will need a system restart.

Answer (score 7):

maybe this is needed too:

```
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts" /v "FontName (TrueType)" /t REG_SZ /d FontName.ttf /f
```

Comment: Copying to "%SYSTEMROOT%\Fonts" plus this worked with Windows 10. No PowerShell needed. Just run these commands with admin permissions.

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to use a PowerShell or VB script.  They basically re-use the shell components that do the same thing in Windows Explorer, and they don't need a reboot.

See here for a PowerShell script that installs all fonts from a directory for Windows 8.1 or earlier:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/fr-FR/winserverpowershell/thread/fcc98ba5-6ce4-466b-a927-bb2cc3851b59

Here is a similar script for Windows 10 (Windows Server 2019) that also updates the Windows Registry:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0c94dcf5-b89d-42e5-a499-06313f46f88b/can-no-longer-install-fonts-via-script-in-windows-10-1809?forum=win10itprogeneral

Also, you'll need to run the script in admin mode.  So if the PowerShell script is InstallFonts.ps1, your batch file needs to look like:

```
powershell -command "Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted" 2>> err.out  
powershell .\InstallFonts.ps1 2>> err.out
```

Any powershell errors will appear in 'err.out' on the same folder as the script.

Comment: Which part of the PowerShell script is supposed to add the registry key?

Comment: @Twonky I've updated my answer to include a link to a PS script that also sets the registry key for the font.  This is needed for Windows 10 or Windows Server 2019.

Answer (score 5):

When you install a font all it does is copy the .ttf file to `%systemroot%\fonts` and add an entry in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts`. This can be automated with a batch file as follows

```
Rem fontinst.bat

copy akbar.ttf %systemroot%\fonts

regedit /s font.reg
```

The font.reg would contain the following:

```
REGEDIT4

\[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts\]

"Akbar Plain (TrueType)"="akbar.ttf"
```

Source: m.windowsitpro.com

Answer (score 4):

So a colleague and I found a powershell solution that requires no admin rights, and does not show any prompts. You can use the name of the font-file to install *and* uninstall. This makes it especially useful for scripting.

Install:

```
# Install-Font.ps1
param($file)

$signature = @'
[DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
 public static extern int AddFontResource(string lpszFilename);
'@

$type = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $signature `
    -Name FontUtils -Namespace AddFontResource `
    -Using System.Text -PassThru
   
$type::AddFontResource($file)
```

Uninstall:

```
# Uninstall-Font.ps1
param($file)

$signature = @'
[DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
public static extern bool RemoveFontResource(string lpszFilename);
'@

$type = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $signature `
    -Name FontUtils -Namespace RemoveFontResource `
    -Using System.Text -PassThru
   
$type::RemoveFontResource($file)
```

You can use them like this from cmd or powershell:

```
> powershell -executionpolicy bypass -File .\Install-Font.ps1 .\myfonts\playfair-display-v22-latin-regular.ttf
> powershell -executionpolicy bypass -File .\Uninstall-Font.ps1 .\myfonts\playfair-display-v22-latin-regular.ttf
```

The solution is based on https://www.leeholmes.com/powershell-pinvoke-walkthrough/ and uses native Win32 functions (`gdi32.dll`). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-addfontresourcew

Comment: Thanks for this! This is very useful especially when you're want to install Font from CI/CD script. Good work!

Comment: You should know that AddFontResource is not installing the font but registering it for usage during the session which means font is not present anymore after reboot. In some cases this is desired but not in all cases. Installed fonts need to be in a special system folder (Windows/Fonts or in user fonts folder) and have a registry key in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts` (or the user equivalent)

Comment: this will not work if you the font name is non-latin

Comment: This is the only way I found working. Thanks for saving my day!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried copying them to the font's folder?

```
copy font.ttf %windir%\Fonts
```

Comment: I have tried above command but it did not work for me in Windows10.

Answer (score 1):

if you are a python fan, following script does the job. This script generates a vbscript for font installation. Searches all the sub-folders for ttf fonts and installs it. You don't need to move any font files.

```py
    import os
    import subprocess
    import time
    
    # vb script template
    _TEMPL  = """ 
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace("%s")
    Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName("%s")
    objFolderItem.InvokeVerb("Install")
    """
    
    
    vbspath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'fontinst.vbs')
    
    for directory, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
        for filename in filenames:
            fpath = os.path.join(directory, filename)
    
            if fpath[-4:] == ".ttf": # modify this line for including multiple extension
                with open(vbspath, 'w') as _f:
                    _f.write(_TEMPL%(directory, filename))
                subprocess.call(['cscript.exe', vbspath])
                time.sleep(3) # can omit this
                    
     os.remove(vbspath)  # clean
```

Run this python script on the root folder

Comment: That code might be not enough. The Windows Shell verb string is dependent on localized version of the Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the task in this way:

suppose you have to install many fonts in subfolders with the following structure recursively:

```
\root_folder
    Install_fonts.cmd
    \font_folder_1
        font_1.ttf
        font_2.otf
    \font_folder_2
        font_3.ttf
        font_4.otf
    \font_folder_3
        font_5.ttf
        font_6.otf
```

To do that, I downloaded the *[FontReg.exe](http://code.kliu.org/misc/fontreg/)* tool on my **Desktop** (change the `path` in the `Install_fonts.cmd` file if it is located somewhere else) and I used it in a `Install_fonts.cmd` batch script like the following, located in `root_folder` (change also its name in the `Install_fonts.cmd` file, if different):

```
@echo off
set back=%cd%
for /d %%i in (%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\root_folder\*) do (
cd "%%i"
echo current directory:
cd
start /wait %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\fontreg-2.1.3-redist\bin.x86-64\FontReg.exe /move
timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul
)
cd %back%
echo Process completed!
pause
```

So, you have to run `Install_fonts.cmd` into `root_folder` as **administrator**, to automate the fonts installation process.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Batch file sample. It works in the current directory.

```
IF  "%*" NEQ "" SET FONT=%*  (

FOR /F %%i in ('dir /b "%FONT%*.*tf"') DO CALL :DEST %%i

) else (

EXIT

)

:DEST

SET FONTFILE=%~n1%~x1
SET FONTNAME=%~n1


IF "%~x1"==".ttf" SET FONTTYPE=TrueType
IF "%~x1"==".otf" SET FONTTYPE=OpenType

ECHO FILE = %FONTFILE%
ECHO NAME = %FONTNAME:-= %
ECHO TYPE = %FONTTYPE%

fontview  %~dp0%FONTFILE%  


GOTO :EXIT
```